# React Routes not Rendering Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I'm currently working on a React application where I'm using React Router for navigation. However, I'm facing an issue where the components associated with routes are not rendering properly.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../components/App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
    if (rootElement) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>,
            rootElement
        );
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    }
});
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react"
import {Route, Routes, } from "react-router-dom"
import Gyms from "./Gyms/Gyms"
import Gym from "./Gym/Gym"

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" component={Gyms}/>
            <Route path="/gyms/:slug" component={Gym}/>
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**Gym.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Gym = () => {
    return <div>This is the Gym#show view for our app.</div>
}

export default Gym
```

**Gyms.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Gyms = () => {
    return <div>This is the Gyms#index view for our app.</div>
}

export default Gyms
```

Despite setting up the routes as above, when I navigate to the routes, I'm not seeing the expected components rendering. Instead, I just see a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your index.js file it seems. I've used basic codesandbox template for react which contains specific index file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./app";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Along with that pass an element as @Puttsche suggested like below

```
<Route path="/" element={<Gyms/>}/>
```

And it worked for me. Here's sandbox working example with your code.

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/eloquent-ellis-gcdgll?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90006356lkzupyl54%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90002356lsq26g017%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90003356l4rn1pvvu%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90005356lkpj4nhz1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522club8dpm90002356lsq26g017%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90002356lsq26g017%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8f1hx0047356l9hhmvbjr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A16%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A16%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522club8f1hx0047356l9hhmvbjr%2522%257D%252C%2522club8dpm90005356lkpj4nhz1%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90004356lqmxsv4ww%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90005356lkpj4nhz1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90004356lqmxsv4ww%2522%257D%252C%2522club8dpm90003356l4rn1pvvu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522club8dpm90003356l4rn1pvvu%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: can you please relink the sandbox? it's not working :/

Comment: Can you tell me what issue you are facing when redirecting to it? As it's working for me. Still adding it in main answer.

Comment: Sandbox not found.

Comment: Can you check now, made it public. And if it resolves your issue kidnly accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could change your code in **index.js** to :

```
import {createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider,} from "react-router-dom";
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
 {
   path: "/",
   element: <Gyms/>,

  },
 {
  path:"/gyms/:slugs",
  element:<Gym/>
  }
]);


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
   <RouterProvider router={router} />
 </React.StrictMode>,
 rootElement
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In React Router v6, the way to specify components for routes has changed. Instead of using the `component` prop, you now use the `element` prop and pass the component as JSX.

Here's how you can adjust your App.js to conform to React Router v6 conventions:

```
import React from "react";
import {Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Gyms from "./Gyms/Gyms";
import Gym from "./Gym/Gym";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Gyms/>}/>
            <Route path="/gyms/:slug" element={<Gym/>}/>
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working :/

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no :/ there is nothing

Answer (score 0):

In index component:

```html
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
    if (rootElement) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App />,
            rootElement
        );
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    }
});
```

In App component:

```html
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Gyms />}/>
              <Route path="/gyms/:slug" element={<Gym />}/>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}
```